Extract non-contiguous data from multiple sheets while extracting from a list with a loop
I am trying to make a tracker where there is a set template of Y/N that would be inputted in this form. I want to track across all this data, eg. track the progress of all the status of these sheets in one mass selection of all the files and not having to open and close 30 times.
Sub ImportDataFromMultipleFiles()
Dim Filenames As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim copyrange As Range
Dim cellrange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'keeps the screen from flickering true/false
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1000").Find("").Select 'where in the tracker the results will appear and the next empty cell, must have the header
Filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*.xls*),*xls*", Title:="Open Files(s)", MultiSelect:=True) 'selecting multiple files

'While loop outside for loop inside, list value in list
'logic is for each ubound file is selected, while each cell follows the list

'the below is a for loop to iterate within the excel sheet

For i = 1 To UBound(Filenames) 'selects all the MOCs ubound giving the position
Workbooks.Open Filenames(i) 'the selected filenames
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("H1").Copy 'the selected range from the selected folders, like D11 D17 D19
'Selection.Copy 'copying the selected values
Windows("tracker automated.xlsm").Activate 'Choosing the file destination
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True 'eventually change the pasting to just text only
Workbooks.Open Filenames(i) 'opening up the selected workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False 'does not make any edits to the MOC
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate 'Offsetting the active cell by one after the filled cell, in the Y-axis

Next i
End Sub

This VBA code extracts data from cell "H1".

How can I include a selection of more cells of eg. D11, D17, D19?
An initial idea was to create a list of coordinates in another worksheet, and to assign said cells so on and so forth like J43, J89 in the event the form I am trying to copy changes, which would mean a massive shift in all the cells where the Y/N would be.

How do I continue to offset the data in rows?
I imagine with more 'extracted data' I need a while/for loop to continue storing the rest of the data in rows.


Most of the code has been copied and adapted from YouTube and other sources.

For example:
Sub ImportDataFromMultipleFiles()
    Dim Filenames As Variant, wb As Workbook, i As Long, c As Range, arrSrc, n As Long
    
    Set c = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1001").End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'next empty cell
    
    Filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*.xls*),*xls*", _
                                            Title:="Open Files(s)", MultiSelect:=True)
    If VarType(Filenames) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub 'user cancelled?
    
    arrSrc = Array("H1", "D11", "D17", "D19") 'all source cells
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Filenames)
        With Workbooks.Open(Filenames(i)) 'reference the opened file
            For n = 0 To UBound(arrSrc)  'loop over source cells
                c.Offset(i - 1, n).Value = .Sheets(3).Range(arrSrc(n)).Value 'write values directly to row
            Next n
            .Close False 'no save
        End With
    Next i
End Sub



Hi time thanks for all the help! However it got stuck on this line:  Set c = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1001").End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'next empty cell                         Not sure how it went wrong? cause for the data range i changed it to the sheet that i want to deposit the data but i keep getting error 'Subscript out of range'

Maybe there’s no worksheet with that name in the workbook where your macro is running (ThisWorkbook)

Strange that it couldn't work for me... there was a work sheet that existed, however I decided to use the function 'activesheet' to obtain the same effect! Thanks you so much for all the help!
